# Android Webview setHttpAuthUsernameAndPasssword ineffective with Google Login

Tags: android, webview, passwords

I and new to Android development and need to implement the activity so that an embedded Webview will be able to login to Google Account Login without user typing in the username and password manually in the first place. I do have the username and password when entering into the activity. I am not supposed to use the AccountManager since there's another thread on it now.

I have read about

1. using WebView.setHttpAuthUsernameAndPassword
2. override the WebViewClient.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest (does not fire the call)

but none seem to work. I have tested manually through the code path and found below:

1. After the WebViewClient.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading was called and I programmatically set username+password using WebView.setHttpAuthUsernameAndPassword, WebViewDatabase.hasHttpAuthUsernameAndPassword returns true, BUT WebViewDatabase.hasUsernameAndPassword is false, and user still see the login screen
2. if WebViewDatabase.hasUsernameAndPassword is true (after user manually entered credentials), WebViewClient(browser) seems not even load the Google Login url and directly go to the callback url

Can someone please provide some insight?

Below is the part of code when I do the setup of webview and webviewclient:

```
final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);   
WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains(ACCOUNT_LOGIN_SERVICE_PREFIX)){
                WebViewDatabase webviewDb = WebViewDatabase.getInstance(getBaseContext());
                if(!webviewDb.hasHttpAuthUsernamePassword()){
                    view.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(
                            "accounts.google.com", 
                            "", 
                            "mygmail@gmail.com", 
                            "mypassword");

                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        }
    };

browser.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
browser.loadUrl(INSTALLED_APP_OAUTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setHttpAuthUsernamePassword()` is for HTTP authentication, like basic or digest auth. The Google account login page does not use any of these, so this is not going to work.

What are you trying to do? You can get a ClientLogin (deprecated) or an OAuth token from AccountManager or the newly announced Google Play Services API. With that, you should be able to login to pretty much any Google service without the user needing to type their password.

Comment: Thanks. I got the Google Play API https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil. What I want to do is to login to through Google Account Service ( Whether the WS Endpoint or the native Adroid AccoundManager ) without the user typing the username and password. I got around this on the web-based version by adding some JavaScriptInterface to traverse the dom and login as the userAgent but that seems hacky. The ideal situation will be programatically add the account to the native Android AccountManager then get token with Play API

Comment: You cannot programatically add a Google account to `AccountManager`, the user needs to go through the wizard and add one. If one is already installed, you can get a token and login.